# How to define derived class if the base class has generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics

Im new to generics c#,

```
 public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}


public class People
{

}

public interface IBaseClass<out T>
{
    T GetPeople(int t);
}

public interface IDerivedClass:IBaseClass<People>
{

}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : People, IBaseClass<T>
{

}

public class Derived : BaseClass<People>, IDerivedClass
{

}
```

I get error while creating the Derived class, as I am new to generics, I don't know how to create derived class
[image]

Comment: You have a constraint that `T` must be a type that implements `IBaseClass<T>`, but `People` does not. You probably intended to define `BaseClass<T>` as `public abstract class BaseClass<T> : IBaseClass<T> where T : People`. Then, of course, you need to implement the `GetPeople` method in `BaseClass<T>` (probably abstractly).

Answer (score 2):

`BaseClass<T> where T : People, IBaseClass<T>` means that `BaseClass<T>` takes in a generic parameter that is required to be `People` and also implement `IBaseClass<T>` (which is `IBaseClass<People>`)

I think you didn't mean to have `IBaseClass<T>` as a generic parameter constraint right? I think you wanted `BaseClass<T>` to implement `IBaseClass<T>`.

In this case you should move `IBaseClass<T>` directly after `BaseClass<T>` like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> : IBaseClass<T> where T : People
```

This now means that `BaseClass<T>` implements `IBaseClass<T>` and T is required (constrained) to derive from `People` (or just be `People`).

Now you will get an error that `BaseClass<T>` needs to implement `IBaseClass<T>.GetPeople`, so just implement that and the code works.

Complete code snippet that works:

```
public class People {

}

public interface IBaseClass<out T> {
    T GetPeople(int t);
}

public interface IDerivedClass : IBaseClass<People> {

}

public abstract class BaseClass<T> : IBaseClass<T> where T : People {
    // this will force Derived to implement GetPeople
    public abstract T GetPeople(int t);
}

public class Derived : BaseClass<People>, IDerivedClass {
    public override People GetPeople(int t) {
        // need to implement this!
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't seen your answer while I was writing my comment above. I would just add that `GetPeople` can be implemented abstractly (which is likely what the OP wants).

Comment: I agree, it is actually better to have it abstract, will change the code to reflect this. Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to add constraint to Derived class ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to constrain/limit? `Derived` class is not a generic parameter, nor does it have generic parameters.